# Sometimes have to wait long till exception is being thrown by HttpClient.execute()

Tags: java, android, http, connection, httpclient

I'm using `HttpClient` to connect to my webservice. I want to implement a simple check if app could connect to this webservice. If not, I want a specific message to appear. This is how I try to achieve it:

```
public static JSONObject getJson(String url) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);

    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if(statusCode == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }
        }
        String json = builder.toString();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        return jsonObject;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        showErrorMessage();
    } 

    return null;
}
```

It works. If I don't have an internet connection, an exception is being thrown while trying to call `client.execute()`, but the problem is that sometimes it throws this exception straight away and sometimes it takes like 2 minutes before it throws it.

What could be a reason? I assume it could be related to trying to connect for a specific amount of time, but I haven't been changing anything in the application and this time differs anyway.

Comment: i guess you should set a connection time out for your request.

Answer (score 1):

Set the timeout parameter to get the exception sooner:

//Value in milliseconds

```
httpget.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout", new Integer(5000));
```